# How to wrap div around div at top left

Tags: html, css

I have this layout.

```
<div class="comment">
<div class="leftpart">
</div>
<div class="rightpart">
</div>
</div>
```

On desktop I leave it as styled where each div is in its own section, nothing is floating inside.

On mobile I want leftpart to be on the top left of comment and right part go to the right of it and wrap around it like this..

```
|-------| Right div |
|Left   | right div |
|  div  | right div |
|<auto->| right div |
|-------| right div |
|right div this div |
|<--- 100% width--->|
```

How do I achieve this without changing my html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to force an elements position to one side, you should use the float CSS attribute. **By floating the .leftpart to the left side, it will remain there and make the rest of the content on the .comment div, wrap around it.**

I made this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/yN7KP/2/

Is this what you are looking for?

HTML

```
<div class="comment">
    <div class="leftpart"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut neque lacus, imperdiet vitae condimentum a, aliquam ut ante. Vivamus nulla quam, rutrum sit amet augue a, semper gravida eros. Nulla sit amet fermentum est, eget lobortis dui. Cras ut pretium justo. Nunc tortor risus, vulputate nec accumsan id, fermentum vulputate felis. Suspendisse mi quam, molestie sit amet pellentesque lobortis, placerat vel nisi. Ut scelerisque lacus magna, quis volutpat purus vulputate at. Sed volutpat risus sit amet lectus sollicitudin porta. Aenean tempus quis est vitae pretium.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.comment {
    width:300px;
    padding:5px;
    background:#f00;
}
.leftpart {
    width:150px;
    height:250px;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
    background:#0f0;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping the text would wrap around. In your example the divs are side by side but I want the leftpart on the top left and the rightpart not exactly on the right but wherever the leftpart isn't within comment.

Comment: @Anthony I've updated the code on the file above to make it do that. It is correct now?